# presidency of drupal template file

Tags: theming

I am new to drupal themeing, I have tried to find the presidency of template files(.tpl.php).. So my question is for a particular scenario if I have html.tpl.php, page.tpl.php, block.tpl.php, node.tpl.php, taxonomy-term.tpl.php, template.php,

1. which file going to run first?
2. if I want to make change some variable's value for page.tpl.php/html.tpl.php then I need to write a function XXX_preprocess_page()/XXX_preprocess_html() according to this listed presidency (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) ?

Comment: Number 2 on your list doesn't seem to actually be a question, it is a statement.

Comment: For number 2 I wanted to be sure from you.

Comment: If you need to know which ones is executed first, then probably you are doing something very, very wrong. You should avoid logic in tpl files. Only things like "if row is odd, add class odd" and similar display issues should be there. Anything that can affect two tpls should probably be in a module, or template.php file.

Comment: If you put debugging in each of the templates you can see which order the debugging prints out, telling you the order. However some templates may render in other templates or their preprocessors, so one template may start rendering then another one could start and finish before that first one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:-template.php file will runs first.you can check it by using die() on top of all files.

answer2 :-For changing some variable's value for page.tpl.php/html.tpl.php use function function XXX_preprocess_page().

**html.tpl.php** -> Handles meta info, body classes

**page.tpl.php** -> Handles content body display

**node.tpl.php** -> Handles content display

**field.tpl.php** ->Handles per field display

Template.php provide display alteration  for all these files.

Comment: This does not say which template file will run first. For example, does html.tpl.php run before page.tpl.php, etc.

Comment: updated please check

Comment: you have the order backwards. a node can't be rendered until the fields are rendered, a page can't be rendered until the node is rendered, etc.

Comment: It's also not always as simple as which one is first. There needs to be more description of the whole process because one template may start rendering first, but then part way through the rendering of that template it renders another template, which finishes before the first one finishes.

Comment: @TBI Infotech your answer is resourceful for me, thanks.

Comment: Please verify the answer if it helped

Answer (score -1):

html.tpl.php will always be used before page.tpl.php (unless you hack core in some way).  typically, variables available in html.tpl.php are not the same as variables available in page.tpl.php, so you shouldn't have an issue with conflicts.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: We can use html.tpl.php in our active theme! It will override the core display for our modification

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, or how it refers to what I said.

Comment: This isn't quite right (or I've misunderstood what you mean) - page.tpl.php will always be processed before html.tpl.php has been processed. It has to, otherwise the page content wouldn't be available to output in html.tpl.php at all. Actually I guess it depends on how you define "used" in this context

Comment: @Clive you're absolutely correct.  theme_preprocess_page will be called before theme_preprocess_html.  I misinterpreted his question.  I thought he meant which is laid on top of which, html.tpl.php inside page.tpl.php or vise-versa.

Comment: Thank you @Clive you have answered my question indirectly.